# holographic remoting can not capture gestures at unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gesture, remoting, hololens

I use Holographic Remoting Player to project the unity uwp program to HoloLens. I can get the unity picture on HoloLens, and I can move around to move the field of view, but the gesture cannot be detected in the unity release program.

I mean that gestures cannot be obtained in release , but gestures can be obtained when using the built-in connector in the unity editor.

```
gestureRecognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
gestureRecognizer.Tapped += RecognizerTapped;
gestureRecognizer.SetRecognizableGestures(GestureSettings.Tap | GestureSettings.DoubleTap | GestureSettings.Hold | GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslate);
gestureRecognizer.StartCapturingGestures();
InteractionManager.InteractionSourcePressed += InteractionSourcePressed;

void RecognizerTapped(TappedEventArgs args)
{
    debugWindows .AddMessage ("tap "+args .tapCount);
}

void InteractionSourcePressed(InteractionSourcePressedEventArgs args)
{
    debugWindows .AddMessage ("pressed");
}
```

that is my test code. and my custom connector is copy at [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.HolographicRemoting.html).

when I used custom connector at anywhere (relase\editor), the "pressed" can printed , but "tap" and any gestureRecognizer's delegate canot printed.

when I used built-in connector at editor, both "pressed" and "tap" are printed.

I run it at many unity versions(2018.2, 2018.4, 2019.1-2019.3), get same result. Am I missing any key settings?

Comment: Is there any error message throw out? Could you follow this step-by-step guide to troubleshoot your Unity Project Settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/configure-unity-project#per-project-settings. Or download the latest MRTK2.3 and Unity2018.4.22LTS and create another new unity project and get started with this document: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html. Do you see the same behavior? This will help narrow down if it's an issue with Unity configuration.

Comment: not any error, just dose not work. the same project worked at hololens, but not work at custom connector with "holographic remoting player". I don't think it has anything to do with MRTK, because I only use low-level APIs. I think it is a unity bug or there are some special settings errors.  Finally, thank you, my post on unity forum did not reply ╮（╯＿╰）╭

Comment: Could you show more information about how did you how to use gesture recognizer, we recommend that you provide an MVCE(stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ,  so that we can locate the issue or find a solution, especially we’d like to know where the gestureRecognizer is defined.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT sorry i'm late. I create a example at github (https://github.com/tjsgtql/HolographicRemotingTest-Unity-19-3-14 ). There are some instructions for use there, if you have any questions, please provide them. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

We believe it is a Unity Side issue, and there is a similar case in Unity's IssueTracker has not been fixed: [HOLOLENS GESTURE INTERACTIONS NOT WORKING WHEN USING THE HOLOGRAPHIC REMOTING FROM UWP APP](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/hololens-gesture-interactions-not-working-when-using-the-holographic-remoting-from-uwp-app)

You can try to resubmit your question to IssueTracker for help

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact, I found a similar problem in the Unity Forum, but after a simple perfunctory, Unity employees ignored this problem. I am very disappointed with them. Almost none of their new technologies are stable.